# Detect incoming phone calls

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to determine when an incoming phone call arrives. I know that applicationWillTerminate will be called if the user takes the call and applicationWillResignActive when the popup with the confirmation message for the call appears, however:
-applicationWillTerminate is also called when the app exits by user request or battery is about to die
-applicationWillResignActive is also called when a UIViewAlert is shown.

Thanks

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short - no, you can not determine if there's an incoming call or another kind of interruption in your application.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It seems `CoreTelephony` might have a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310332/detecting-the-call-events-in-ios

Answer (score 3):

I found this article on handling incoming calls; terminating resuming and persisting state,.

It might help you..

http://www.tomwhitson.co.uk/blog/2009/04/handling-interuptions-to-your-app/

```
(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
        //our app is going to loose focus since thier is an incoming call
        [self pauseGame];
}

(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
        //the user declined the call and is returning to our app
        [self resumeGame];
}

(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication*)application{
        //the user answered the call (or quit the app) so save the
        //game as we are shutting down
        [self saveGameState];
}
```

Comment: This is useful for many scenarios but you cannot be 100% certain applicationWillResignActive is called as a result of an incoming phone call.

Answer (score 3):

I know this questions is really old, but in case someone else reach this question just like me, there is an audio session delegate to detect if the audio will be interrupted (mainly by a Phone call).

For any app playing audio this approach works for detecting incoming iphone calls.

Here is a link to Apple documentation for: [Handling Audio Interruptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html)