# How to get the last declined number of iphone in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, core-telephony, calllog

I need to get access to the call log of an iphone programatically.  I came to know that it is not possible to get the call log in ios sdk.  Is there any new API's available to get access of the call log of an iphone approved by apple.  I've gone through the app "Agile Reply" in Appstore which accesses the call log of an iphone.

Guy's any suggestion from ur side will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Agile Reply application does not read the call log of the iPhone, otherwise it would not be on the App Store.

Instead, what it probably does is it registers itself with a CTCallCenter, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4/3320212#3320212), so that when it is running and a call comes in it's able to know the number of that call.  It's then able to reply with a text message when the user opens it after the call is completed.

Comment: @Brad Larson: How can we know the phone number of the call that comes in using CTCallCenter.

Comment: @Monish - Set up a call event handler block and provide it to the CTCallCenter.  You'll receive updates for every call that happens when your application is active or in the background.  See Don's answer here for an example of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4/3320212#3320212 .  Perhaps the `callID` property on the CTCall instance given to that callback will let you figure out the phone number for the call (I've never tried this myself).

Comment: @Brad Larson:But I am totally confused how to get the phone number using CallID propery.If possib can u post any sample code so that it is really helpful to me.

Comment: Can anyone please help me how to get rid of this..!!

Comment: @Monish, have you managed to retrieve the CTCall of the declined call? Now you only need to retrieve the phone number from CallID?

Comment: @Micheal Kessler:Yes I managed to get the call status and callID and now I want to retrieve only the Phone number.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access to the call log.