# How to get the Phone number from the callID(call Identifier) of call which returned form callcenter in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, core-telephony

I had tried to get the call status and call Identifier of a call using coreTelephony.framework.And Need to get the phone number of the incoming call.Is it possible to get the phone number using the CallID.If so can anyone suggest me with sample code.

Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 1):

callID is simply used to differentiate multiple active cellular calls. It is not possible to get the number from this.

Comment: Then how cum I get the phone number?Please refer this link and suggest me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260617/how-to-get-the-last-declined-number-of-iphone-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

you can not get phone number with call id by core telephony frame work. But i know a way form which you can get phone number that is given in this question's answer. see this link
[same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828157/how-can-i-access-call-log-history-on-ios5)