# How can I access call log history on IOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5, calllog, core-telephony

I used FMDatabase and this path (/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db) to access the call logs on IOS4. After I updated to IOS5, it just gave me a "permission denied" exception. I know the call log file is there, just apple remove the permission.
So I am thinking, is there anyway we can push the call log file to ICloud and take it back to our application? Or use CoreTelephony framework to get the CallID first, and use that ID to point somewhere and get the call detail info? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no supported way of doing this.  You're likely to get rejected by Apple if you attempt it.

Answer (score 0):

you have only one way but that will approved by apple or not. I don't know. I am telling you that answer but it may be risky.

You can see this link [call details](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)