# Incoming call information+iphone

Tags: iphone

I have one application in which i have to first find the number of  the incoming call and send message on that number,but i know that apple doesn't allow this… so how can i add this functionality in my application?is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last declined number of iphone in iphone sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260617/how-to-get-the-last-declined-number-of-iphone-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question. Apple doesn't allow it, so no, it's not possible under normal circumstances. If you're targeting only jailbroken phones then perhaps the answer is different (I don't know that it is). If you're playing by the rules, though, the only solution is to have the user initiate the process and let them tell you the number to use.