# How to get number when call is received in iphone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, phone-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incoming call information+iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469081/incoming-call-informationiphone)

I am beginner for iPhone. How to get number when call is received in iPhone . I don't have basic idea about that.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get this information, and I would be very surprised if Apple add this feature ever to their sdk. There will be lot of people around who will misuse this feature.

The most you can get about a phone call is using [Core Telephony framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html). It lets you detect the status of the call.

> A CTCarrier object gives you information about the user’s cellular
>   service provider, such as whether it allows use of VoIP (Voice over
>   Internet Protocol) on its network. **A CTCall object gives you
>   information about a current call, including a unique identifier and
>   state information—dialing, incoming, connected, or
>   disconnected**(emphasis mine).

That is it.

Just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469081/incoming-call-informationiphone) also. Might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible. Apple does not allow this.
Would you like it if one of your apps that you had been using picked up a phonenumber that called you and posted it on the internet? That may be one of the reasons why apple doesn't allow this…

Comment: I think the same as you. I wonder why the access to the addressbook is so free though.