# Is there a concrete check to see if a user has accepted a phone call?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know when a call is accepted applicationWillResignActive and applicationWillEnterBackground both get called. But they seem to also get called for some other cases.

Is there a way to check if the user has ANSWERED the incoming phone call rather than decline or let it ring out.

As there maybe cases when the app gets a phone call while the app is already in the background and I need to be able to get some code to execute.(Hope I havent been to vague)

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Core Telephony framework, and the CTCallCenter object.  I think it does what you're asking for...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604

Comment: Additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4/3320212#3320212