# Can I put a loop into dispatch_async when my app enters in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, core-telephony

I want to build an application for iOS.  The idea is to launch a `UILocalNotification` when a call state  is `Connected`.  I try to use `dispatch_async` a block in the method `applicationDidEnterBackground` and I put into this block a loop `while(!isConnected)` to know when should the `UILocalNotificacion` be launched.  The loop checks the call state and decides when to launch the notification.

What I need to know is , is that way the correct way to solve my problem? or does anyone have a better idea?

Ok, this my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
 {

// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
isAlive = YES;

NSLog(@"BackgroundTimerRemaining %f", [application backgroundTimeRemaining]);

// verufy status of call
bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

[self readLocalVariableCalling];

__block int connected = 0;

__block int callingTemp = 1;//((NSNumber*)[self.datos objectForKey:@"calling"]).intValue;
NSLog(@"callingTemp: %d", callingTemp);

__strong typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        //isAlive = YES;
        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.
        while (callingTemp == 1)
        {
            if (callCenter != nil)
            {

            callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call)
            {
                NSLog(@"Loop - Call EventHandler state: %@", call.callState);
                if([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected])
                {

                    NSLog(@"disconnected");
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
                    callingTemp = 0;
                    connected = 0;
                    [weakSelf.datos setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"calling"];
                    [weakSelf saveLocalVariableCalling];

                }
                if ([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateDialing] &&
                    connected == 0)
                {
                    NSLog(@"connected - Call EventHandler state : %@", call.callState);
                    connected = 1;
                    if (callingTemp == 1
                        && weakSelf.timerTableViewController.currentTimer)
                    {

                        TimeDto *currentTimer = weakSelf.timerTableViewController.currentTimer;
                        NSInteger seconds = currentTimer.value.intValue;

                        NSLog(@"minutos a segundos = %d", seconds);

                        NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds];
                        UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

                        if (weakSelf.notifyAlarm)
                        {
                            weakSelf.notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
                            weakSelf.notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                            weakSelf.notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
                            weakSelf.notifyAlarm.soundName = @"road.caf";

                            NSString *messageTimer = NSLocalizedString(@"messageTimer", nil);
                            weakSelf.notifyAlarm.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:messageTimer, ((int)currentTimer.value.intValue / 60 ) , (currentTimer.value.intValue % 60)];

                            [app scheduleLocalNotification:weakSelf.notifyAlarm];
                        }
                    }
                }


            };
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"callCenter is null");
            }
            //NSLog(@"loop call state");

        }

        NSLog(@"Call Finished");


        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }

});
}
```

Comment: I really don't like the idea of busy waiting. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4

Comment: Ok, but this is in iOS 4, now we have iOS 6, I think I could be a possible solution

Comment: Actually, my concern is that `while(!isConnected)` will waste your processor's cycles.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I think that `while(!isConnected)` not running much time because the loop are break when call state is Connected.

Comment: Why negative bounce in my question?, I should be entitled to ask, because no question is bad :(

Comment: this is barely a real question. give us code, not single lines.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how you schedule the work, once your application is in the background it's allowed only a certain amount of further processing before all activity is stopped. Trying to `dispatch_async` isn't magically going to buy you permanent multitasking.

So, no, I don't think this solves your problem.

Comment: Ok, but I know that `dispatch_async` have a timeout (10 minutes) I think that time is enough for my purpose, Don't you think?

Comment: It has no official documented timeout. You can use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to request some background processing but the amount of time you'll be permitted isn't documented. The root of the problem, I think, is that what you want to do is explicitly something Apple don't want you to do. Is this for the app store?

Comment: The undocumented time is 2 minutes, I believe