# Detect notification in app

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, sms, detect

In apps such as Tiny Wings, it will detect a new SMS or phone call and pause the game for you. How can I detect this in my app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect incoming phone calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742223/detect-incoming-phone-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `UIApplication` delegate method

```
- applicationWillResignActive:
```

[Protocol UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:)