# Best way of handling interruption (such as phone call, battery warning) when in the middle of a task

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uiapplicationdelegate, appdelegate

I'm aware of the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1742350/998117) with `applicationWillResignActive:`, but that's a method within the app delegate. If I'm in a view controller that is obviously separate and doing a task, how do I tell that view controller to pause its activity from within the app delegate?

Is it best just to do this through delegates? Or is there another, more preferred way?

Comment: Mutter to yourself, throw the phone on the ground, and jump up and down on it.

Answer (score 1):

For the view controllers which require it you can make them observers of the application notifications. There are a range of notifications such as `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` which are all posted to the `defaultCenter` (`NSNotificationCenter`).